# How to split a path using ant?

Tags: ant

I have for example a path:

> Path: "Abc/dbaklbdf/akldfa/das/adsa"

I need to split it on `/` to access the values.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the Ant code you have so far. Also, what would you like to do with this split string?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in javascript:

```
'Abc/dbaklbdf/akldfa/das/adsa'.split('/')
```

output:

```
["Abc", "dbaklbdf", "akldfa", "das", "adsa"]
```

Comment: i don't think i have javascript on it - do i?

Comment: You have not mentioned from where are you getting this path. you are using javascript, python, c# or what ?

Comment: i'm using ant and the path is a custom file path

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725033/how-to-extract-part-of-a-filename-with-apache-ant